# how pull from multiple arrays to build a listing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

So I have this working function that pulls in data from another data to build a listing. However the data I need spans over multiple arrays so as a result these items return "undefined".

Right now I'm only pulling from the products array located at http://api.example.com/items?key=123456789 (this has the .productName and .itemCode )

.description and .price are part of another array at http://api.example.com/itemCode?key=123456789

Is there way to pull all these together with jquery to build one dynamic listing?

```
function foodQuery(){

    var foodURL = "http://api.example.com/items?key=123456789";

    $.ajax({
        url: foodURL,
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: "text/plain",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {

            $.each(json.products, function(index, product) { 

                // build product block
                var htmlString = '<div class="product large-3 columns">';
                //open imgwrap
                htmlString += '<div class="imgwrap">';
                //get img src
                htmlString += ' <img class="item_img" src="http://api.example.com/assets/images/' + product.itemCode + '@2x.jpg" />';
                // close imgwrap
                htmlString += '</div>';
                // open textwrap
                htmlString += '<div class="textwrap">';
                // get productName
                htmlString += '<h1 class="product_headline">' + product.productName + '</h1>' ;
                // get itemCode
                htmlString += '<h4 class="item_id" >#' + product.itemCode + '</h4>';
                // get description
                htmlString += '<p class="product_desc">' + product.description + '</p>';
                // open price
                htmlString += '<div class="price">';
                // get price & close div
                htmlString += '<span class="dollar"><span class="usd">$</span>' + product.price + '</span> <span class="product_desc">per weight</span></div>'
                // close divs
                htmlString += '</div>';

                //console.log(htmlString);
                $('.listing').append( $(htmlString) );

           }); //end each

        }, // end success
        error: function(e) {
           console.log(e.message);

           $('.listing').append( '<h1 class="errmsg" >Sorry, there was an unkown error.</h1>' );
        } // end error
    }); // end ajax request
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try creating array containing URL for each `$.ajax()` request , utilize `$.when()` with `this` set to `$` , `.apply()` to call `foodQuery` with each URL within `urls` array as parameter for each `$.ajax()` request

```
var urls = ["http://api.example.com/items?key=123456789"
           , " http://api.example.com/?key=123456789"];

function foodQuery(url) {

    var foodURL = url;
    return $.ajax(settings);

}

$.when.apply($, $.map(urls, function(url, index) {
  return foodQuery(url)
}));
```

Comment: sorry guess I'm still a total newb. How would this fit into the code I currently have?

Comment: @user2882684 Tried `js` at post ? Adding parameter to `function foodQuery(url){` , utilizing `$.when.apply` should call `foodQuery` with each URL within `urls` array , append `htmlString` from each call to `foodQuery` to `.listing` element ?

Comment: where does my .each() loop go?

Comment: @user2882684 _"where does my .each() loop go?"_ Only portion of `foodQuery` adjusted was adding parameter `url` at `function foodQuery(url) {` , `var foodURL = url;` ; remainder of `foodQuery` , adding `return` before `$.ajax()` call . See http://jsfiddle.net/on23mbxg/1/